# PHP Get Current Filename After URL Rewrite

Tags: php

I know `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` can be used to get the url of the current page, but this doesnt work if the URL is a htaccess URL rewrite.

How can I get the real (not rewritten) filename of the current php file?

For example I go to http://site.com/page/ it rewrites and displays http://site.com/page.php

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];` will just give me the rewrite, I want the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the php constant `__FILE__` as in:

```
 echo __FILE__;
```

Comment: Note that this is the name of the actual file in which this constant is called.  If called withini an include file, you will get the include file's name. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] would be more reliable if you need to use this within an include.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` to get the current script or `__FILE__` to get the current file. difference being with included files. if file A.php includes file B.php, in file B.php `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` would have A.php as that is the calling script and `__FILE__` has the exact file where that line is being called which would be B.php. ex:

A.php:

```
<?php
include("B.php");
```

B.php:

```
<?php
echo '__FILE__ has: '.__FILE__.'<br />'; //shows B.php
echo '$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] has: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'<br />'; //shows A.php
```