# cURL filetime short URL

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get last mod date with curl filetime but when the URL is rewritten (I think) it doesn't seem to work. I don't know what's causing this and where to start my search.

Though it returns HTTP code 200 (??).

It works when script name and extension is visible in UR (e.g. http://www.otherdomainremotecompany.com/products/index.html/).

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domainremotecompany.com/products");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result !== false) {
$timestamp = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
$statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
$last_mod_date=date("d-m-Y", $timestamp);
echo $last_mod_date;
echo "<br />";
echo $statusCode;
}           
curl_close($curl);

//output:
//01-01-1970
//200
?>
```

Comment: It might be possible that the rewritten URL is handled by some front controller, and generally the controller might not be setting the last modified date for the route. Try with `curl -v {url}` in terminal.

Comment: Are you solved this issue?

Comment: no, unfortunately not! I still got to find out what @DeepakChaudhary meant.

Comment: What I meant is, when a response is generated by a script(controller) the server might not be able to produce last modified date, since there is no file.

Comment: Update: To try to understand what happens on server and where url (secretly) points to I even have used programs like fiddler, url snooper and httpnetworksniff but without succes. This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185607/php-get-current-filename-after-url-rewrite I found looks a lot like my question but I'm not sure if I can use `__FILE__` on a remote url.